# Default foreignkey value in Django

Tags: python, django

I know this has been asked countless times but none of the solutions seem to fit my needs. I am trying to dynamically set the default value of a foreign key from a foreign key in another app. 
Heres the models including the function to get the default value. This code doesnt error and it does put a value in the dropdown (without 'default = ...' the dropdown in the template just displays '---' as the initial/default value), its just the wrong value. It uses the first entry in the 'RevisionSettings' table and doesnt change.

### Code

#### models.py (calc app)

```
from django.db import models
from settings.models import RevisionDefaultType, RevisionSettings

def get_default_rev():
    queryset = RevisionDefaultType.objects.values_list('defaultrevisiontype', flat = True)
    return queryset


class PstCalc(models.Model):
    revision_type = models.ForeignKey(RevisionSettings, default = get_default_rev)
```

#### models.py (settings app)

```
from django.db import models

class RevisionSettings(models.Model):    
    global_revision_type = models.CharField(max_length = 5, unique=True, blank = True)
    global_revision_description = models.CharField(max_length = 300, unique=True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["global_revision_type"]

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.global_revision_type


class RevisionDefaultType(models.Model):
    defaultrevisiontype = models.ForeignKey(RevisionSettings)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["defaultrevisiontype"]

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
            return unicode(self.defaultrevisiontype)
```

Comment: Do you mean `limit_choices_to` instead? You are trying to assign a `ValuesQueryset` (an iterable) against  `default`

Comment: I want all the choices available, I just want the default/initial value to match the current entry in 'RevisionDefaultType' id=1.

Comment: So you should be getting the first element back right, not the entire queryset values

Comment: Yes. I tested using 'print (queryset)' in the function and checked what was printing in the shell. It displayed the foreignkey id as expected. It did produce a funny result in that it displayed the result 3 times, as if in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. All it needed was a small tweak found on this site:
http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/250

#### Function

```
def get_default_rev():
    queryset = RevisionDefaultType.objects.values_list('defaultrevisiontype', flat = True)
    for query in queryset:
        return query
```

Hope this helps anyone else that has a similar problem and if anyone sees any issues with this code please feel free to correct me.